# Why is Object constructors property globally scoped?

Tags: javascript

Given the following:

```js
function MyClass() {
  this.name = "Agnus"

  return function() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}


const user = new MyClass() //this = "MyClass"
const r = MyClass() //this = "window"

console.log(name) //Agnus, this = "window"
r() //Agnus, this = "window"
```

My expectation was that on calling r(), I will get a error as the value of "this" is window for its case but instead it returned me "Agnus". On checking, I found that the properties of the object constructor MyClass are available from global.

[image]

I am having little difficulty to wrap my mind around such behavior, so it will be really nice if someone can explain me a bit about this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you call `MyClass()` without `new`, you essentially run `this.name = "Angus"` where `this` is `windows`. Thats why `window.name` is set to `"Angus"`

Comment: `const r = MyClass() //this = "window"` calls the constructor as a function, so that sets the global *name* property to *Angus*. Properties of the global object are available as variables (they're virtually interchangeable, but not quite). See [*What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `new`, you set the `this` to a new empty object whose internal prototype is the constructor's `.prototype`. That is:

```
new MyClass()
```

```
function MyClass() {
  // `this` is now equivalent to Object.create(MyClass.prototype)
```

But if you explicitly return an object from a constructor function, the `this` will essentially be discarded, and the returned object will be used instead. Here, the returned object is the function, and the

```
this.name = "Agnus"
```

line assigns to an object which is never referenced again.

In contrast, when you don't use `new`, and the function you call isn't a property of an object (or bound, or an arrow function), `this` will be either the global object (in sloppy mode), or `undefined` (in strict mode). In sloppy mode,

```
function MyClass () {
    this.name = "Agnus"
```

does

```
window.name = "Agnus";
```

And then when you invoke the returned function later with `r()`, since it's not a property of an object, its `this` is the global object - whose `name` is `Angus`.

To reduce confusion, I recommend

- Avoiding returning objects explicitly from constructors
- Always using `new` when invoking a constructor

You don't *have* to, but if you do that, you'll confuse yourself (and other readers of the code) less.

[Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is a good idea too.